# Python script - API call fails due to JSON arguments

Tags: python, api, cmd

I am trying to pull reports through a (shadowserver) API - doc [here](https://www.shadowserver.org/what-we-do/network-reporting/api-documentation/):

The python script is written by ShadowServer and I have tested it with the simple usage example they are providing:

```
$ ./call-api.py test/ping '{}'
{"pong":"2020-10-26 23:06:37"}
```

Thus far, everything works fine. I can submit additional calls and I get a response back.

However, when i try to pass a JSON parameter to the script (that is executed in command prompt), such as the example below:

```
os.system('''[some_directory]\\call-api.py reports/query '{ "help":true }' pretty''')
```

I get the following result:

```
JSON Exception: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I believe that it is an issue with the quotes - single/double/triple.. but I've tried everything and it keeps returning the same result.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: you might want to try `subprocess` see if you get the same result, e.g. `subprocess.Popen(["[some_directory]\\call-api.py", "reports/query", "{'help': True}", "pretty"])`

Comment: @Matthias thanks for the suggestion. In this instance, I am getting ``JSON Exception: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)``

Comment: JSON needs double quotes and lowercase booleans, so you want `'{"help": true}'`, alternatively if you have that as dict you could just `json.dumps({"help": True})` and not worry about quotes.

Comment: I second the `json.dumps`, I use that usually so I don't have to worry about this stuff

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll post an answer and please mark it as accepted if it solved your problem :))

Comment: @Matthias of course. I'd gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try `subprocess` to see if you get the same result, e.g. like this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([
    "[some_directory]\\call-api.py",
    "reports/query",
    '{"help": true}',
    "pretty",
])
```

or use `json.dumps` to not worry about any quoting

```
import subprocess
import json
subprocess.Popen([
    "[some_directory]\\call-api.py",
    "reports/query",
    json.dumps({"help": True}),
    "pretty",
])
```

[SitiSchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7228176/sitischu) came up with the `json.dumps` idea.